# PHP Readonly Properties or Constants?

Tags: php, properties, constants, php-8.1

Since PHP 8.1 the native support for [readonly properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.readonly-properties) arrived. But we already have constants with visibilities.

Please help me to answer these two questions:

1. Which differences are between using constants and properties?
2. When to use which one?

Comment: One big difference is that you can't set class constants dynamically at runtime, which you can do with readonly properties (from the constructor). There's also a big difference in how you access the two. Unless the property is static, you will need to have an instance (and all instances can have different values), while constants can always be access without an instance.

Comment: I would also add that `readonly` is a property decoration, just like visibility (public, private, protected), that signals intent, which in this case being immutability. Once an instance of a class with such a property has been initialized, the class author wants everyone to know, including themselves, that certain fields are guaranteed to never change, either intentionally or accidentally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Difference in write**

> One big difference is that you can't set class constants dynamically
> at runtime, which you can do with readonly properties (from the
> constructor).

**Difference in read**

> There's also a big difference in how you access the two. Unless the
> property is static, you will need to have an instance (and all
> instances can have different values), while constants can always be
> access without an instance.

Props  to [M. Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/m-eriksson)

Comment: So a readonly property is the better choice because it requires an instance and therefore this property would not be visible in the global scope unless the property was static, whereas a constant is always static and therefore can be called from the global scope. Therefore, one could say that a class constant is equivalent to a static readonly property in terms of its functionality.

If you e.g. code an ORM-Class then I would recommend to store the corresponding database table in a readonly property so that this information is only accessible from within the class.